# Read from string into stringstream

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

When I try to parse whitespace seperated double values from a string, I found this curious behaviour that the string is read out in a cyclic manner.

Here's the program:

```
stringstream ss;
string s("1 2 3 4");
double t;
list<double> lis;

for(int j=0; j!=10; ++j){
    ss << s;
    ss >> t;
    lis.push_back(t);
}

for(auto e : lis){
    cout << e << " ";
}
```

Here the output:

```
1 2 3 41 2 3 41 2 3 41
```

If I append a trailing space as `s= "1 2 3 4 ";` I get

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
```

Now the questions:
1) If I don't know how many entries are in the string s, how do I read all into the list l?
2) which `operator<<` am I actually calling in `ss << s;`? Is it specified to read circularly?
3) Can I do the parsing in a better way?

Thanks already!

---

Here's the fixed code (thanks to [timrau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718379/timrau)):

```
// declarations as before
ss << s;
while(ss >> t){
   lis.push_back(t);
}
// output as before
```

This produces:

```
 1 2 3 4
```

as desired. (Don't forget to clear your `stringstream` by `ss.clear()` before treating the next input. ;))

Another useful comment from [HeywoodFloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090100/heywoodfloyd): One could also use boost/tokenizer to "split" the string, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: You don't need to put `s` several times into the stream. move `ss << s;` outside the loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can test the return value of `>>`.

```
while (ss >> t) {
    lis.push_back(t);
}
```

It's not specified to read circularly. It's `ss << s` appending `"1 2 3 4"` to the end of the stream.

Before the 1st loop:

```
""
```

After 1st `ss << s`:

```
"1 2 3 4"
```

After 1st `ss >> t`:

```
" 2 3 4"
```

After 2nd `ss << s`:

```
" 2 3 41 2 3 4"
```

Then it's clear why you get `1 2 3 41 2 3 41 2 3 41` if there is no trailing space in `s`.

Comment: Got it! Thx a lot.  I was thinking that the `<<` would read space seperated words as the `cin >> some_string` does.

Answer (score 0):

then use `s.length()` for strings containing unknown number of entries, if you use your approach. 
Or, as suggested by timrau, just initialize your stringstream once.

```
stringstream ss;
string s("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");
ss << s;
double t;
list<double> lis;
while (ss >> t) {
    lis.push_back(t);
}

for(auto e : lis){
    cout << e << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) includes a boost tokenizer example.  You may want to tokenize your string and iterate through it that way.  That will solve the no trailing space problem [timrau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718379/timrau) pointed out.